# Trying to push new object into array (should be very simple, new to javascript)

Tags: javascript

Very new to javascript - basically I have a simple HTML form wherein one can enter their first name, last name, and number, and I want to add that to the array contactList but I'm running my head into a wall! My console.log command is showing an empty array.

```
var contactList = [];

function Contact(f, l, n) {
    this.fname=fname;
    this.lname=lname;
    this.num=num;
}

    var submit = document.getElementById("submit");
    submit.onclick = function(){
        var firstname = document.getElementById("fname").value;
        var lastname = document.getElementById("lname").value;
        var number = document.getElementById("num").value;

        contactList.push(new Contact(firstname, lastname, number));
    }

console.log(contactList);
```

Answer (score 2):

you are using undefined variable inside `Concat` constructor. you pass `(f,l,n)` and assign `fname,lname,num`

edit it to be:

```
var contactList = [];

function Contact(f, l, n) {
this.fname=f;
this.lname=l;
this.num=n;
}

var submit = document.getElementById("submit");
submit.onclick = function(){
    var firstname = document.getElementById("fname").value;
    var lastname = document.getElementById("lname").value;
    var number = document.getElementById("num").value;

    contactList.push(new Contact(firstname, lastname, number));
}

console.log(contactList);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two reasons why you don't see new value in the `contactList` array:

1. If you use `input` or `button` elements with type `submit` inside of the `form` element, click on it will trigger the HTTP request to the URL specified in form's `action` attribute - this will *reload* your page, so you will lose the page context and you will see an empty `contactList`
2. Your last `console.log` statement is outside of your click handler, so it will be executed with (at that moment) empty `contactList` right after registering click handler.

To fix the second issue just move `console.log` inside of your click handler. The first issue could be fixed in different ways:

1. Don't use control of type `submit`. This will not trigger page reload
2. At the very beginning of your click handler use `preventDefault` method on event, which is passed as argument to click handler function. This will have prevent the default action of clicking on control of type `submit`. For example:

   submit.onclick = function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       // ...
   }
3. Don't use the form element at all if you need just collect some values from inputs and process them somehow.

Also, as `@Omar Elawady` mentioned in another answer - you have wrong assignments inside of your constructor. You pass (f,l,n) and assign fname, lname and num

Comment: Tried this and it didn't work. Something weird actually happens, something briefly flashes on my console and then it disappears, leaving an empty console window. Perplexed.

Comment: @vikram add `e.preventDefault();` at the beginning of you submit handler. It seems like you use regular form so click on submit will reload your page and will clean your page context. `e` is a parameter passed to `submit` handler. Check out @adeneo's answer for it

Comment: @vikram or just use <button> or any other element styled as button instead of <input type="submit"/> and `onclick` handler.